# Alprazolam (xanax) longterm effects?

Tags: drug-withdrawal

Is Alprazolam harmful longterm. I've been taking this med 3x-0.25mg for a week. Quite frankly, many of my colleagues/students/friends consume it as well.

I'm a little bit afraid since I've seen some scary videos on youtube of people taking it regularly who have gotten serious "longterm" side effects.

I'm also curious how come for the past 30 years since alprazolam has been released there hasn't appeared any better and safer drug which treats anxiety well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short-term memory loss and an increasing tolerance to and dependence on the medication. To answer your second question, there are many avenues for treating anxiety, first you should try lifestyle changes like improving diet, exercise, reducing stress, and psychotherapy. There are other safer drugs that can help with anxiety and those include but are not limited to Zoloft, Prozac, Trazodone, BusPar, or Wellbutrin. The poster above me mentioned Valium but that is in the same chemical class as alprazolam and has similar adverse effects. I highly recommend that you consult with your doctor.

Comment: Hi! I do agree with your answer. However, I do think that you should provide references (indicating that you are a PharmD candidate isn't sufficient. There are a lot of MD providing answers on Health SE and they still provide references to support their claims). Also, it would be worth giving the compound name of the drugs and not the market name which can change from one country to another. Thank you. Best wishes.

Answer (score 1):

**Long term usage can cause:**

- [Dependance](http://www.parkroyalhospital.com/addiction/prescription-drugs/xanax/signs-symptoms-withdrawal). Physical and pschological.

[Others are](http://drugabuse.com/library/the-effects-of-xanax-use/#lasting-health--effects-of-xanax):

- Cognitive deficits.
- Delirious states.
- Depression.
- Psychotic experiences.
- Aggressive and impulsive behavior.
- Slight memory impairment

Other medicines you could take would have to be analyzed and prescribed by a doctor, but might be Zoloft, Valium, or etc. The factors depending on their being prescribed varies so the choice of meds differs.